# How to load the datafile to Automated Excel Sheet document?

Tags: c++, excel, automation, activex

I have a MFC/C++ project that uses the ActiveX Document (Automation) approach for opening Excel Sheet embedded object. Unfortunately, Excel.Sheet obj API does not have methods to load data from a prepeared htm/cvs file. So, I can not load the prepared data. The only object capable of loading data from a file is "Workbooks" (method Open(...)), but it always creates a new Sheet object, and does not use existing one. All examples of use embedded Excel.Sheet document offer to fill a table cell "by hand" and no one shows how to open an existing file in it.

So, how to load html/cvs datafile to Automated Excel Sheet document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, there is no way to create ActiveX Excel Sheet Document initialized by file format does not coincide with xls/xlsx. First you need to convert the html format in xls/xlsx and then open through standart OLE API (OleCreateFromFile).
A conversion I described [in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742784/export-html-files-with-images-to-excel-single-xls-file).

Answer (score 1):

You can embed any files (of any types) into Excel worksheet using OleObjects. This is example code for attaching file:

```
BOOL InsertFileToWorksheet(Exl_Worksheet &ws, LPCTSTR lpFilePath, LPCTSTR ObjName)

{ 
    RemoveOldOleObj(ws,ObjName);

    VARIANT vFileName;
    str_to_vt(vFileName,(char*)lpFilePath);
    ExlOLEObjects ole_objects;

    BOOL bRes(TRUE);
    try{
        ole_objects = ws.OLEObjects( vOptional );

        COleVariant left(10l),top(10l),width(1l),height(1l);
        Exl_OLEObject objSrc = ole_objects.Add(vOptional,vFileName,vOptional,vOptional,vOptional,vOptional,vOptional,
                        vOptional,vOptional,vOptional,vOptional);
        objSrc.SetName(ObjName);
    }catch(...){
        bRes = FALSE;
    }

    VariantClear(&vFileName);
    return bRes;
}

void RemoveOldOleObj(Exl_Worksheet &ws, LPCTSTR ObjName )
{
    ExlOLEObjects ole_objects;
    try{
        ole_objects = ws.OLEObjects( vOptional );
    }catch(...){
        return;
    }

    VARIANT vObjName;
    str_to_vt(vObjName,(char*)ObjName);
    Exl_OLEObject obj;

    try{
        obj = ole_objects.Item(vObjName);
        obj.Delete();
    }catch(...){
    }
    VariantClear(&vObjName);

}
```

The full source code (c++) you can find [in this article](http://strongcpp.blogspot.com/2013/04/excel-how-to-insert-user-file-into.html).