# export HTML files with images to Excel single XLS file?

Tags: c++, excel, automation, ole

I'm trying to export HTML file with pictures to Excel using C++ OLE Automation.

Sample of code:

```
#import "\\alpha\sdk\mso\office12\mso.dll" rename( "RGB", "MSORGB" ) rename("DocumentProperties", "MSODocumentProperties") rename("SearchPath", "MSOSearchPath")
using namespace Office;
#import "\\alpha\sdk\mso\office12\VBE6EXT.OLB" rename( "RGB", "MSORGB" ) rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")
using namespace VBIDE;
#import "\\alpha\sdk\mso\office12\excel.exe" rename( "DialogBox", "ExcelDialogBox" ) rename( "RGB", "ExcelRGB" ) rename( "CopyFile", "ExcelCopyFile" ) rename( "ReplaceText", "ExcelReplaceText" ) no_auto_exclude
#import "\\alpha\sdk\mso\office12\msword.olb" rename( "DialogBox", "WordDialogBox" ) rename( "RGB", "WordRGB" ) rename( "CopyFile", "WordCopyFile" ) rename( "ReplaceText", "WordReplaceText" ) rename( "ExitWindows", "WordExitWindows" ) rename( "FindText", "WordFindText" ) no_auto_exclude

// Create Excle application OLE obj...
Excel::_ApplicationPtr pApplication;
HRESULT hRes = pApplication.CreateInstance(_T("Excel.Application"));
if (hRes==S_OK) {
    pApplication->PutDisplayAlerts(MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_NEUTRAL), SORT_DEFAULT), VARIANT_FALSE);
    pApplication->PutCopyObjectsWithCells(MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_NEUTRAL), SORT_DEFAULT), VARIANT_TRUE);

    // Open prepeared for export HTML file
    Excel::_WorkbookPtr pBook = pApplication->Workbooks->Open( _bstr_t(szHTMLPath), _variant_t((long)Excel::xlUpdateLinksAlways), vtMissing, vtMissing/*_variant_t((long)Excel::xlHtml)*/ );
    if (pBook!=NULL) {
        //Save opened HTML file as XSL file
        hRes = pBook->SaveAs(_bstr_t(szXLSPath), _variant_t((long)Excel::xlWorkbookNormal), vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, Excel::xlNoChange, _variant_t((long)Excel::xlLocalSessionChanges), _variant_t(false));
        if (hRes==S_OK) {
            // All is ok
        }
        pBook->Close();
    }
    pApplication->Quit();
}
```

Unfortunately, the img pictures from of the html code is not converted into an **embedded image**, but in the **external linked images**. How do I convert images to store them internally in the XLS file as an embedded object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brief talk [on a Microsoft forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/0579f931-9ec6-426d-a74f-fc8399f2ff54) allowed to form a more or less working code.

```
Excel::ShapesPtr pShapes = Excel::_WorksheetPtr(pBook->Worksheets->Item[1])->Shapes;
for (long nIndex=1; nIndex<=pShapes->GetCount(); nIndex++)
{
    Excel::ShapePtr pShape = pShapes->Item(nIndex);

    const Office::MsoShapeType nType = pShape->Type;
    switch (nType)
    {
    case Office::msoLinkedPicture:      
        {
            const float rLeft       = pShape->Left;
            const float rTop        = pShape->Top;
            const float rWidth      = pShape->Width;
            const float rHeight     = pShape->Height;
            const _bstr_t szPath    = pShape->AlternativeText;

            Excel::ShapePtr pNewShape = pShapes->AddPicture(szPath, Office::msoFalse, Office::msoTrue, rLeft, rTop, rWidth, rHeight);
            if (pNewShape)
            {
                pShape->Delete(); 
                nIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```